# Tidyverse packages

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm installing `tidyverse` and getting this conflict error message. How should I resolve it?

```
✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
```

I have already tried to install `dplyr` through the install package but I still keep getting this prompt

Comment: This just means that `dplyr` and `stats` packages both have functions named `filter()` and `lag()`. You don't need to uninstall the packages. If you need to use either of those functions, you should specify which package version you want to use, i.e. `dplyr::filter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have multiple packages loaded with the same function, use the `::` in the pipe to specify the package name.  A common type of issue occurs when `plyr` is also loaded as there is `summarise/mutate` functions that are common between these packages

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
   dplyr::select(mpg, cyl) %>%
   group_by(cyl) %>%
   dplyr::summarise(mpg = sum(mpg))
```